TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable during Django migrations
When I run python manage.py migrate, I encounter the following error:
File "/home/seyedbet/virtualenv/WanderSight/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable

Django Version: 4.2,
Python Version: 3.9
How can I resolve this?

Share the migration file.

@willeM_VanOnsem I resolved the issue by switching from "mysql.connector.django" to "django.db.backends.mysql" in my settings.py file, and now it works perfectly. This was caused by the database backend configuration in my Django project. Thank you

I was using "mysql.connector.django" with "mysql-connector-python" for the database backend. This configuration led to the error. Here's what I had in my settings.py:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'your_db_name',
        'USER': 'your_db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'your_db_password',
        'HOST': 'your_db_host',
        'PORT': 'your_db_port',
    }
}

To fix the issue, I switched to "django.db.backends.mysql" with "mysqlclient" as the database backend. Here is the updated configuration that resolved the error:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'your_db_name',
        'USER': 'your_db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'your_db_password',
        'HOST': 'your_db_host',
        'PORT': 'your_db_port',
    }
}

After making this change, running python manage.py migrate worked without any errors.
